# Excel data from specific cells to Sharepoint Master excel file

Tags: excel, sharepoint, excel-formula

I made a data collection excel sheet for multiple team members at work.  Each workstation has a copy of the sheet.  I want them to be able to send specific cell data to the Master sheet for collection purposes that is located on the team's Sharepoint site.  Any recommendations?  I have already made the Xactive button and set up a module for this

Comment: `I have already made the Xactive button and set up a module for this` Please include your code.

Comment: Sub Test2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wbMaster As Workbook
Dim wblocal As Workbook
Dim masterNextRow As Long
Set wblocal = ThisWorkbook

Comment: Dim dir, fullpath As String
dir = CurDir()
SharepointAddress =   Master.xlsx
Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open(fullpath)
masterNextRow = wbMaster.Worksheets("Master").Range("A" & wbMaster.Worksheets("Master").Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Offset(1).row

Comment: 'wrong declaration name masterNextRow -> masterNewRow
wbMaster.Worksheets("Master").Cells(masterNextRow, 1).Value = wblocal.Worksheets("").Range("B3").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Master").Cells(masterNextRow, 2).Value = wblocal.Worksheets("Data").Range("B2").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Master").Cells(masterNextRow, 3).Value = wblocal.Worksheets("Data").Range("B4").Value
wbMaster.Worksheets("Master").Cells(masterNextRow, 4).Value = wblocal.Worksheets("Data").Range("F3").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub